# Centering image on Nivo Slider using default theme?

Tags: jquery, css, nivo-slider

To anyone who uses Nivo Slider, is there any straightforward way (or not) to center the image on the slider? I'm aware that Nivo Slider was designed to display images which perfectly "fit" the box (unlike the way I'm using it), but for technical reasons I'd rather try have the images centered instead of make all my images perfectly fit the Nivo box's width and height. Currently my Nivo slide looks like this:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12453703/nivo.png

Sorry I haven't provided any code examples of me trying this. My CSS knowledge isn't too great and most of my attempts at fixing the problem have either been looking at solutions on the web (and attempting to apply said solution), or trying out random one-lines in my stylesheet in an attempt to fix the problem.

If you'd like to know what CSS files I'm using, I'm using the default theme which can be downloaded here:
http://cloud.github.com/downloads/gilbitron/Nivo-Slider/nivo-slider2.7.1.zip

Thanks, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position of image is loading in javascript file. Edit "jquery.nivo.slider.js" (Please make sure to use this file instead of "jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" in the header.)

Goto line 85:

```
//Set first background
        slider.css('background','url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat');
```

Find the above line. Change it to:

```
//Set first background
        slider.css('background','url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat center');
```

Now you can see that your first image is in center. Just play around that file and you definitely make the whole images to center.

**EDIT:**
Find this function: // Add slices for slice animations. Line 253.
Edit the else part of that. Line 262

```
background: 'url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat -'+ ((sliceWidth + (i * sliceWidth)) - sliceWidth) +'px 0%'
```

By changing 0% to 50% makes the image center vertically. Getting closer...

**EDIT**

Edit the above line once more and replace with below line.

```
background: 'url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat 50%'
```

This will definitely works..

**EDIT**

Forget about all the above edits. Just replace your jquery.nivo.slider.js file with [this one](http://www.mediafire.com/?anxza91liua4ab2).

Comment: We're close! First image is centered, however images after that aren't centered. I'm not sure if maybe it's a bug I introduced or whether I'd have to do more editting in the .js file? Anyways I gotta head off in a sec, hopefully we're nearly there. Cheers.

Edit: There was another line I did a copy and paste on, now when I click on one of the little circle buttons on the bottom the images center. Now the only thing left to fix is, centering the images when the slides change automatically.

Comment: Check my Edited part in Answer.

Comment: Check my latest edit in answer. Hope this will solve your problem. :)

Comment: Thanks - doing the edits in the .js file up to your 2nd edit seems to break the transition effect (ie not make it work properly). Up to the first edit is fine. Did it work perfectly for you? I'm still doing some play arounds myself, maybe worst case scenario if it's too much of a hassle to fix I can maybe restrict my slide to certain transitions which work properly.

Comment: Its perfectly working for me. Just check my .js file. [jquery.nivo.slider.js](http://www.mediafire.com/?84st3yb3jgo7oa8)

Comment: EDIT: I just extracted the fresh demo files and applied your .js file, and referenced that .js file in demo.html, but it's still not working correctly. The first image centers, but when it transitions the images go back to the top-left corner. I decided to upload my files, could you maybe check this out (sorry for the inconvenience)? http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12453703/nivo-slider.zip

Comment: Hey I had worked on your .js file. Add this file. It seems to be perfectly working. :) [new .js file](http://www.mediafire.com/?anxza91liua4ab2)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7332/discussion-between-chrispy-and-libin)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to make horizontal centered background and you want all transitions to work well, you can do the following:

1. You need to know the actual width of current image
2. You need to calculate an offset from which slices (or boxes) for this image should be added:

   `var mySliceOffset = (vars.currentImage.attr('width') - $('body').width()) / 2;`

(in this example slider container width is set to 100%)

1. Then edit background properties:

   `background: 'url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat -'+ ((mySliceOffset+sliceWidth + (i * sliceWidth)) - sliceWidth) +'px 0%'`

Answer (score 1):

Create a wrapper div and center nivoslider inside that div.

Html:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
        <img src="images/slide.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#wrap { 
    position: relative;
    height: 500px; 
    width: 500px; 
}
#slider { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -125px; // Half the height
    margin-left: -125px; // Half the width
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Edit `demo.html` and add an extra wrapper like so:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
    <div class="ribbon"></div>
        <div id="slider-wrap"> <!-- Extra wrapper -->
            <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                <img src="images/toystory.jpg" alt="" />
                <a href="http://dev7studios.com"><img src="images/up.jpg" alt="" title="This is an example of a caption" /></a>
                <img src="images/walle.jpg" alt="" data-transition="slideInLeft" />
                <img src="images/nemo.jpg" alt="" title="#htmlcaption" />
            </div>
            <div id="htmlcaption" class="nivo-html-caption">
                <strong>This</strong> is an example of a <em>HTML</em> caption with <a href="#">a link</a>.
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Add this inside `style.css` in the demo files:

```
#slider-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -123px; /* 246/2 */
    margin-left: -309px;/ /* 618/2 */
}

.slider-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
    width: 1000px;
    background: red;
}
```

Find this line and comment the margin rule:

```
.theme-default #slider {
    /* margin:100px auto 0 auto; */
    width:618px; /* Make sure your images are the same size */
    height:246px; /* Make sure your images are the same size */
}
```

Download the modified example and investigate the code http://www.mediafire.com/?9f7z9ku4n1ikiba

Comment: The whole page seems to play up and look weird if I apply your example. I already have nested divs from the demo example in the zip, which is:

<!-- language-all: lang-html -->
 
 <div id="wrapper">

        <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
            <div class="ribbon"></div>
   
            <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
      
   <img src="images/up.jpg" alt="" />
   <img src="images/walle.jpg" alt="" />
     
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

Comment: I edited my answer with the solution. You can find a download link to the modified demo.

Comment: Wow - A for effort! But your solution wasn't quite what I had intended (sorry to say that, feel bad when I do). In the example you've shown, you've centered everything inside the red box. Whereas what I wanted to try and do was, center the image inside the box. I tried some random images with your example and the images still sit at the top-left corner of the slideshow box, rather than centered.

If you're unclear take a look at the image in my original post, everything is positioned fine except for the image of the car, which I'd like to be centered inside its box.

Comment: But what's the point of doing that?. I don't get it. Can't you just center the nivoslider like I'm saying and then just absolute position the arrows and bullets to the edges of the wrapper? You need to use same size images with nivoslider anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this css.

```
.nivoSlider img {
    background-position:center center;
}
```

Comment: I just tried this, unfortunately it didn't work. I tried also adding this to my own styles.css, since I have two style sheets that are referenced in index.php ... nivo-slider.css, and style.css

Answer (score 0):

For me, the simplest solution required 3 things:

1. Assuming that on narrow viewports your images should span the full width of the viewport, specify a maximum width for your images (in pixels) at the point you want them to stop growing as the viewport expands and simply begin centering within the viewport itself.
2. Make sure that the width of ALL of your images is **greater or equal to the the maximum width** you selected in the first step. (If you have a skinny image you can still make it work. Read on.)
3. Put the Nivo slider inside a wrapper and center it.

For step 1, I used 1220px.  This was simply because my images began to get cropped off at the bottom when they were any wider than 1220 pixels.  Pick whatever you want.  The bigger the number the wider the viewport can be before centering begins.  However, the downside is that all of your images need to be at least as wide as whatever you pick.

For step 2, just follow the rule.  If you have an image that's not wide enough but you still want to use it, you can do so by a simple edit to the image as follows:

> Let's assume you have an image that's 800x600 and you picked 1220 in step 1.  This image won't work because it's too small.  However, if you make a new image with an acceptable width (i.e. 1220x600), you can fill the entire image with whatever background color is being used behind the slider.  Then, take the 800x600 image and paste it right in the center of your new 1220x600 image.  This new 1220x600 image should center properly.

For Step 3:

**CSS**

Add the following to nivo-slider.css

```css
.slider-wrapper
{
 position:relative;
 max-width: 1220px;   -   Change this width to whatever you want
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
}
```

*Optional - You should edit the "max-width" setting of your ".nivo-Slider img" property so that your images will load a little more nicely:*  If you don't do this, what happens is that the first image (if larger than the max-width) will flash in full size an then quickly adjust. To apply the edit, simply change the max-width property from "none" to whatever max width you specified in the slider wrapper.  See example below.

```css
.nivoSlider img {
 position:absolute;
 max-width: 1220px;
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
```

**HTML**

Put your slider inside your new slider wrapper.

```css
<div class="slider-wrapper">
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
*slider stuff*
</div>
</div>
```

Enjoy the symmetry!